How would 10x better batteries change urban transportation?
Recent (as in the past 30 years) improvements in battery technology seem to have enabled three main transportation technologies to become economically viable:

Electric cars
Electric scooters
Electric bicycles

These are all old technologies, with prototypes of each going back over 100 years (electric cars going back to the 1800s), but lithium-ion batteries being the main thing to push them into the mass market and they're now all common sights in cities in developed countries.
Now, let's say a battery is invented with 10x the energy density and 5-10x the charging speed of a lithium-ion battery that costs the same per kg as lithium-ion batteries do today.  I'm assuming this would push most (if not all cars) to become electric.  What new form of urban transportation becomes economically viable that is used by a substantial fraction of the population (at a minimum, 1% of people in a typical city in a developed country)?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

If the only change is to the batteries themselves, then nothing happens to urban transportation. One of the biggest current limits to electrification is… current. There's not enough current available in the wires supplying the charging infrastructure right now.
(For this reason, don't be surprised if, in real life, car companies are encouraged to put PV cells onto the cars themselves even though that's not a good place to put PV cells and doing that can't fully replace normal charging: PV is cheap, and that reduces the demand on the grid).
That said, cheap storage (even if not dense) has a whole bunch of other side-effects, including an even faster roll-out of renewables because renewables go from "cheap power" to "no-brainer".
Long-distance/intercontinental electric air travel would probably become possible from a 10x increase in battery density, but that's not "urban".

If you have the beefy power grid to allow the urban transport to get charged 10x faster, regardless of anything else, you'll probably see a lot of surprising health and safety issues — having the best charging standard go from 350 kW to 3.5 MW implies someone, somewhere, having an explosive interaction with that power getting past a badly maintained bit of insulation and into their finger (not that 350 kW isn't going to be similarly dramatic to a mere human body).
If you've got the batteries and the means to charge them, this would also allow all the heavy vehicles to also become electric: double-decker busses, articulated lorries, heavy construction equipment.

You may be asking: what about flying cars/ambulances?
To which I say: We have them, they're called "helicopters", and the biggest problem is you need a license, and licenses are expensive.
We may develop drones to get around the pilot licensing requirements, but we were already going down that path anyway without batteries, so we're not likely to see any new flying things that we otherwise wouldn't have seen.

This appears to be a frame challenge. Would you agree?

Drones are very much happening with batteries; without magically better batteries I think is more accurate.  Urban drones are almost universally electric models.

[Long-distance/intercontinental electric air travel would probably become possible from a 10x increase in battery density] Do you have reasoning for this? I can imagine it not mattering, but 10x better than the hottest new electric car batteries is still about 5x worse than an equal mass of jet fuel, just on a joule for joule basis.

Re: beefed-up chargers and safety, I would be less concerned about electrocution, more concerned about impurities that increase resistive heating. Lotta house fires in the future of that world, I think. (Although I could see an argument that, rather than install 3.5 MW charging equipment in your home, you'd just have a small charger sufficient for topping up between short commutes. If you deep-discharged the battery on a long trip you'd go to somewhere with specialist infrastructure to recharge safely, akin to a gas station.)

Infrastructure gets upgraded when demand hits. It may slow the process but not halt it.
Anyways, for every home owner domestic solar basically fixes the grid problem.
Landlords might need laws dropped on their heads to force their hands.

@JBH I could buy that it's a frame challenge, from your link. I've not looked at that kind of thing closely enough before to have strong feelings either way.

@gs indeed, but batteries also get a factor of ~2 due to how inefficient combustion is as a source of mechanical energy, which makes it a question of "how big a fuel tank is OK for all the other design constraints?": https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/50768/which-jet-engines-have-the-highest-thermal-efficiency

What are the very general effects of urban life following a near-magical improvement in battery technology? This sounded far too vague, but I think it actually has a simple answer. I think it will have less effect than almost anywhere else.
Cities are dense places. They have trains to draw people in from the suburbs, which can run on electrical power. Offices and homes are densely packed towards the centre. A commute in London will go at roughly the speed it went when traffic was horse drawn. Electric bicycles may have extended the range people are willing to travel by bike or scooter. Going by car is difficult as you have to park at the other end. We might use a car for shopping, or the school run, where we start and end in the same place. Public transport such as trains and buses can run on the present electric technology.
Now add the effects of the internet. I can order the bulk shopping from home the way the local order used to arrive from the village shop when I was a boy. I can order all sorts of stuff on line. Present battery power is very well suited to the stop-start driving of delivery vehicles. I work at home for most of the week. If I could get the car to drive itself close to the railway station, I could get it to take me there in the mornings and pick me up in the evening, avoiding a parking charge which is more than half the cost of the railway fare.
Most of my motoring fits into a 50-mile round-trip. I could hire a car for long journeys and family holidays, when I would fill the vehicle with luggage and people. This is when the new battery technology would come into its own.
What is this magic battery power? For this, I will have to use a frame challenge. There are promises of fast-charging sodium cells using cheaper materials. However, if you fill a car with conventional fuel, you are taking on energy at about 50 megawatts. Assuming your petrol engine is 40% efficient (high, but possible) this would be like charging a 12V cell for a 100% efficient electric engine at 50x0.4/12 = 1.667 million amps. Fast charging is a lot slower than that, but it does cause problems for the electricity supply and it still is significantly less efficient than trickle charging overnight.
US ships were using diesel-electric powertrains back in the thirties. Diesel-electric locomotives because common in the UK in the sixties. This works best at large scales. The solution to getting it to work at car scales is to make the engine out of ceramic, insulate it, and have it run hot at its optimum rate, and have an electric power train to deliver the power to the wheels see for example Carnot Engines. A car may have several ceramic power units, which can be turned on and off according to the power budget. Is this recyclable? It could be if we generate fuel from algae, or other waste products. Is this efficient? It is lighter than batteries which have to carry their oxidiser, reducer, and electrolyte with them in a cleverly insulated package, rather than just fuel in a tank, and oxidiser from the air.
This might mean you have petrol farms alongside solar cell power farms in the country. You may have car parks and drop-off zones near to bus stops and railway stations in the commuter belt. Drones may manage the last mile for deliveries where the skies are clear. But the city may hardly change at all.
